# Retrieve Messages from office 365 cloud Using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

[image]I am migrating my mailbox to office 365 cloud from outlook 2007. My pl/sql block is not reading email from office365 cloud. same code is working in outlook 2007 which in  on premises. i am using Mail_Client API which is working fine when the mailbox is in on premises. After moving to cloud office 365, same pl/sql code is not reading the emails.
I have seen same issue is raised by many but no solution.

https://www.databasedevelop.com/article/13567914/Read+mails+from+Outlook+office365+inbox

Comment: reading email from MS products is not standard Oracle functionality, so you'll need to provide more details about what's going on. For instance, do you get any error messages? Also, have you configured [the ACL](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1)?

Comment: Thank for response. Yes ACL is configured. It throws authentication failure error.

Comment: That is clearly a piece of bespoke code written by somebody in your organisation. You can't expect us to diagnose that.